# meteor.js email.send not working when trying to send to array of users

Tags: javascript, arrays, email, meteor

so my email.send is working but only if im sending email only to one user.
here is the code inside of a meteor.method:

```
sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text) {
    check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);

    this.unblock();

    Email.send({
        to: to,
        from: from,
        subject: subject,
        text: text
    });
}
```

});

working client code:

```
Meteor.call('sendEmail',
            'yechielxxx@gmail.com',
            'boazxxx@gmail.com',
            'test',
            'testing meteor email');
```

not working:

```
 Meteor.call('sendEmail',
                ['yechielxxx@gmail.com','boazxxx@gmail.com','boazxxx@walla.co.il'],
                'boazxxx@gmail.com',
                'test',
                'testing meteor email');
```

what am i missing here? this is what docs.meteor says "to String or Array of strings
RFC5322 "To:" address[es]"

im using an array of users everything should be working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this on `v0.6.5.1` and `Email.send` will take an array, but your code isn't running because the check will fail when you pass an array for `to`. As written, it's looking for all inputs to be strings. If you modify it to something like:

```
check(to, Match.OneOf(String, [String]));
check([from, subject, text], [String]);
```

Then you can pass a string or an array to `sendEmail` and it should work.